# String - method ToString

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, string, tostring

Is it possible to display string with ToString() method with custom format?

For example, I have string like: "123456789" and I would like to display as "123 456 789".

I tried like this:

```
string myString = "123456789"
mystring = myString.ToString("{0:### ### ###}")
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Apparently, `ToString("### ### ###")` does what you want. You only need the accolades and formatting number when using `string.Format`.

Comment: Note: `string` does not have a `ToString` method that accepts a format string. You'll have to convert your string to a numeric type first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx). Here is an example:

```
string myString = "123456789";
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
               "{0:### ### ###}", Convert.ToInt64(myString)));
```

Output:

> 123 456 789

Comment: how would you insert a space after every third number with `String.Format` ?

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at this simple solution:

```
Convert.ToInt64("123456789").ToString("### ### ###");
```